# R: resourcing code in snow workers

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm using snow parApply() to distribute processing tasks to a number of workes on the local machine. The problem is that if I change the code in one of the functions the workers will not be aware of the changes.

How can I 'resource' the source code files in the workers?

**EDIT**

I can't call source() on my cluster to re-eval all my functions:

```
cl = makeSOCKcluster(rep("localhost", 5))
> clusterCall(cl, getwd)
[[1]]
[1] "/home/user"

[[2]]
[1] "/home/user"

[[3]]
[1] "/home/user"

[[4]]
[1] "/home/user"

[[5]]
[1] "/home/user"

> clusterCall(cl, source, 'ets.load.R')
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  5 nodes produced errors; first error: cannot open the connection
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update it in each worker using `parallel::clusterCall`

Comment: Correct, and the same in `snow` upon which (this part of) `parallel` is built.

Comment: There is also a function called clusterCall() in the snow document. "clusterCall calls a function fun with identical arguments ... on each node in the cluster cl and returns a list of the results."